# SetFieldValue for a TaxonomyField

Tags: taxonomy, term-store, spfield

I'm on a solution where I create a term with some subterms in the termstore. After that I create a sitecolumn and a listcolumn. When setting a value to the listcolumns with

```
 taxField.SetFieldValue(item, term, language);
```

taxonomyfied I get an argumentexception.

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldValidationException: The given guid does not exist in the term store
```

The term is filled correctly and has the same guid as the element in the termstore (checked it with powershell).

What can I do to fill the newly created taxonomyfield or get around the excpetion.

[Update]
It works with

```
taxField.SetFieldValue(item, term, language);
```

and the solution Stefan Bauer underneath this post. The problem is anywhere else (if you want to know read comments underneath stefan bauers post)

[Update #2]
The problem was the taxonomy hidden list in the site. It was not up to date since I deleted a the field in the sitecolumns. Stefan Bauer pointed to his blogpost where the solution is first: Update your sharepoint and second: try TaxonomySession.SyncHiddenList(SPSite). 
Blogpost: http://www.n8d.at/blog/sharepoint-2010/anatomy-of-managed-metadata-fields/

Comment: You should add an answer to your own question based on the updates.

Comment: Check the managed metadata site column is referencing the right group with right termset value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set a taxonomy field you should use [TaxonomyFieldValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfieldvalue.aspx) or [TaxonomiFieldValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfieldvaluecollection.populatefromlabelguidpairs)

You first need to find the term in your term store:

```
            TaxonomyField taxonomyField = item.Fields[field] as TaxonomyField;
            TaxonomyFieldValue taxValues = new TaxonomyFieldValue(taxonomyField);
            TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(site);
            TermStore termStore = session.TermStores[taxonomyField.SspId];
            TermSet termSet = termStore.GetTermSet(taxonomyField.TermSetId);
            TermCollection terms = termSet.GetTerms(termLabel);
```

If you retrieved the term from the term store you can then set the value as follows

```
        TaxonomyFieldValue taxonomyValue = new TaxonomyFieldValue(taxonomyField);
        taxonomyValue.TermGuid = term.Id.ToString();
        taxonomyValue.Label = term.Name;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I get the same error.

Comment: This will only work if you first got the term from the Termstore.

Comment: I've got it 2 lines above from the termstore.

Comment: A little refactoring showed me that the function GetValidatedString() throws the error. But I just don't know why.

Comment: I added some code how to get the term you are looking for. You also need to loop over the termcollection.

Comment: I first get the parentterm and later getting the correct childterm with  

Term term = choiceTerm.GetTerms(choiceValue, language, false, StringMatchOption.ExactMatch, 1, true).FirstOrDefault();

I tried it with looping throught but got the same error.

Comment: Now I deleted the Termstore (Service) and created it new. Now it works. How should I tell the client?

Comment: Strange thing. Have you checked the ULS and event viewer log?

Comment: OMG this only happens in an english termstore, with a german teamsite where the taxonomyfield created in sitecolumns is deleted once and created after that. Because the field exists somewhere hidden after it is deleted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3679/discussion-between-stefan-bauer-and-steffen-schindler)

Answer (score 0):

For the error ...was not retrieved with all taxonomy fields

What others may find useful is that your Term Store field is starting at the wrong location within the Term Store.  Hence the code cannot find your Term Store values as it only iterates below the Term Store field starting location which has been set.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the taxonomy hidden list in the site. It was not up to date since I deleted a the field in the sitecolumns. Stefan Bauer pointed to his blogpost where the solution is first: Update your sharepoint and second: try TaxonomySession.SyncHiddenList(SPSite). Blogpost: http://www.n8d.at/blog/sharepoint-2010/anatomy-of-managed-metadata-fields/